# векторы и матрицы c++

Tags: c++

Как из строк матрицы получить векторы?

**UPD:**

Описание: матрица (2 мерный массив) имеет 2 столбца , и эти столбца нужно превратить в 2 вектора (массива).

Comment: Некорректный вопрос. Сначала опишите, какое представление матриц и векторов вы используете. А то напрашивается ответ: повернуть строку на 90 градусов)

Comment: Открою вам страшную тайну: строки матрицы являются векторами.

Вот если говорить про столбцы... То там, да, надо что-то делать.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть у Вас есть массив int m[10][5];

Что из этих индексов 0<=i<10 и 0<=j<5 - строка а что столбец - исключительно ваше восприятие. Давайте считать, что i - это столбцы! Отлично, вот получаем указатель но i-ый столбец:

```
int * a = m[i];
```

Главное - не менять это представление пока существует этот массив.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен тип вектор. Либо если нужно без типов - просто выделяйте память под необходимую длину массива и переписывайте из матрицы значения в вектор проходом по столбцу.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector < vector<int> > matrix;
vector < vector<int> > columns(matrix[0].size(), vector<int>(matrix.size()));
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].size(); j++)
    {
        columns[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
    }
}
```